# I have a problem uploading blink

Tags: arduino-mega

I am uncertain what a serial monitor does when I try uploading blink.  I get:

```
problem uploading to board avrdude stk500_recv910 programmer is not responding
```

Comment: Sorry, that has to be a typo: programmer is you?

Comment: You are correct: this is a real message. It means you have misswired your serial lines.

Comment: Actually it can be any serial port error.

Comment: Blink uploads easily, so we'll need more information - Are you using a USB serial cable, for instance?  Have you selected the correct board and port?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably not chosen the right COM port. Try picking a different COM port, if using USB cable.

Comment: This answer is rather terse and would have probably been better as a comment. If you could expand your answer, maybe explaining where to change the COM pot and a screenshot, that would be great.